Upserting with multiple tables in MYSQL
I'm trying to create code so that a table (created from 2 joins) is updated when 1 or more source tables are updated.
This is the original code:
REPLACE INTO operations (
    customerId,
    customerCreated
    _Id
    paymentsCreated
    status,
    amounts,
    commerceName)
SELECT
    cu.customerId,
    cu.customerCreated
    p._Id
    p.paymentsCreated
    p.status,
    p.amounts,
     c.commerceName)
FROM
    payments p
LEFT JOIN
  commerces c ON c._id = p.commerceId
LEFT JOIN 
  customers cu ON cu.customerId = p.customerId


As you can see there are 3 tables and each of them can change at any time by modifying a record created long ago.
Well, I'm trying with this code but but I don't know if it is the best option and it is the fastest, because the tables have millions of records.
REPLACE INTO operations (
    customerId,
    customerCreated,
    _Id,
    paymentsCreated,
    status,
    amounts,
    commerceName
)
SELECT
    cu.customerId,
    cu.customerCreated,
    p._Id,
    p.paymentsCreated,
    p.status,
    p.amounts,
    c.commerceName
FROM
    payments p
LEFT JOIN
    commerces c ON c._id = p.commerceId
LEFT JOIN 
    customers cu ON cu.customerId = p.customerId
WHERE
    cu.updated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR
    p.updated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR
    c.updated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);


Did you forget to ask a question? Why duplicate the data at all? Presumably the payments always have a customers row and a commerces row, in which case your left joins should be inner joins. If you really need to populate the operations table you could use triggers instead of bulk updates. You might be able to improve the efficiency of the select element of your query by using the union of three separate selects, one for each of your updated criteria.

Thanks, I actually forgot to ask the question explicitly, but it is in the sense that you answered, how to optimize the query.
Yes, I could change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, although not all payments always have customers or commerces due to how they are updated.
Regarding this: "You might be able to improve the efficiency of the select element of your query by using the union of three separate selects, one for each of your updated criteria" How could I build it?

Splitting your select into three separate selects and then combining them with UNION may perform better, assuming that you have indices on the updated columns.
SELECT cu.customerId, cu.customerCreated, p._Id, p.paymentsCreated, p.status, p.amounts, c.commerceName
FROM payments p
LEFT JOIN commerces c ON c._id = p.commerceId
LEFT JOIN customers cu ON cu.customerId = p.customerId
WHERE p.updated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION

SELECT cu.customerId, cu.customerCreated, p._Id, p.paymentsCreated, p.status, p.amounts, c.commerceName
FROM payments p
INNER JOIN commerces c ON c._id = p.commerceId
LEFT JOIN customers cu ON cu.customerId = p.customerId
WHERE c.updated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

UNION

SELECT cu.customerId, cu.customerCreated, p._Id, p.paymentsCreated, p.status, p.amounts, c.commerceName
FROM payments p
LEFT JOIN commerces c ON c._id = p.commerceId
INNER JOIN customers cu ON cu.customerId = p.customerId
WHERE cu.updated >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);


Thanks I see your method. It's very interesting. I assume this would be done as an intermediate step, since there could be duplicate records because a record was updated on the same day by both the payments and customers sides. Then you would have to perform the upsert where the duplicate records would be removed, is that correct?

No, the UNION dedupes by default. See Set Operations using DISTINCT and ALL.
